# How do we delete all of the comments of an user if comments don't have their own model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I am trying to figure out how to delete an user's comments on mongoose, but I am not sure how, but it's mainly because the comments on my application don't have their own models.

If I really wanted to do this, I would give comments their own model, but I want to keep my schema as it is. So my PostSchema looks like this:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    user: [ 
        {
            type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'users'
        } 
    ],
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    likes: [
        {
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'users'
            }
        }
    ],
    comments: [
        {
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'users'
            },
            text: {
                type: String,
                require: true
            },
            name: {
                type: String
            },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }


    ],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now 
    }

});
```

I would like to be able to delete all of the user's comments, but not the posts. Is this something that can be done, or the only way to do this is to create a model for comment and give it an one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will remove the user's comments from every post.

```
MyPostModel.updateMany({}, { $pull: { comments: { user: userIdToRemove } } });
```